# Pester 5 - Access Multiple Variables in Nested Loop

Tags: powershell, pester-5

I am converting Pester tests from V4 to V5 and in line with the best practices, moving the loops from `foreach()` to `Describe -ForEach{}`. The tests are a standard set that checks if each function has comment based help and this requires multiple nested loops.

This question is similar to [Pester 5 variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806373/pester-5-variable-scoping-issue-beforediscovery-it) and [Working with nested foreach](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/1731) and I have referred to [Data Driven Tests](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/data-driven-tests), but my problem goes deeper as firstly, I need multiple levels of nested loops and secondly, I need access to multiple variables. The first variable `$helpParameterNames` is used by the loop and the value of each row is checked to see if it exists in the second variable `$parameterNames`

**V4**
In V4, the arrays are accessible throughout the whole set of Describe/Context/It blocks so when I get to the last `foreach` loop, both `$helpParameterNames` and `$parameterNames` are accessible.

```ps
$commands = Get-Command -Module ModuleName

foreach ($command in $commands) {
    $commandName = $command.Name
    $help = Get-Help $commandName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    Describe "Test help for $commandName" -Tag Help {
        
      <It Tests Removed>
        
        Context "Test parameter help for $commandName" {            
            $common = 'Debug', 'ErrorAction', 'ErrorVariable', 'InformationAction', 'InformationVariable', 'OutBuffer', 'OutVariable', 'PipelineVariable', 'Verbose', 'WarningAction', 'WarningVariable'
            $parameters = $command.ParameterSets.Parameters | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique | Where-Object Name -notin $common
            $parameterNames = $parameters.Name
            $helpParameterNames = $help.Parameters.Parameter.Name | Sort-Object -Unique
            
            foreach ($parameter in $parameters) {
                $parameterName = $parameter.Name
                $parameterHelp = $help.parameters.parameter | Where-Object Name -EQ $parameterName               
                
                <It Tests Removed>
            }
            
            foreach ($helpParm in $helpParameterNames) {
                It "Should find parameter $helpParm in the function" {
                    $helpParm -in $parameterNames | Should Be $true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**V5**
In V5 as the setup code has to be defined in the `BeforeDiscovery` block, I can't get it to be available in the sub-blocks automatically. I can make it accessible by passing the array into the `-ForEach` as a HashTable, but then it will treat it as 1 object and not iterate over it, which is fine for `$help`, but not for `$helpParameterNames`

```ps
BeforeDiscovery {
    $commands = Get-Command -Module ModuleName
}

Describe "Help Rules" -Tags Build, Help -ForEach $commands {
    BeforeDiscovery {
        $commandName = $_.Name

        $common = 'Debug', 'ErrorAction', 'ErrorVariable', 'InformationAction', 'InformationVariable', 'OutBuffer', 'OutVariable', 'PipelineVariable', 'Verbose', 'WarningAction', 'WarningVariable'
        $parameters = (Get-Command $commandName).ParameterSets.Parameters | Where-Object -Property Name -NotIn $common | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique
        $parameterNames = $parameters.Name
        $help = Get-Help $commandName -Full -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    Context "General Rules for $commandName" -ForEach @{help = $help} {

        <It Tests Removed>

        Describe "Parameter Rules for <parameter.Name>" -Tags Help, Parameter -ForEach $parameters {
        
            BeforeAll {
                $parameter = $_.parameters
                $helpParameterNames = $help.Parameters.Parameter.Name | Sort-Object -Unique
                $parameterHelp = $help.parameters.parameter | Where-Object Name -EQ $parameter.Name
            }

            <It Tests Removed>
        }

        It "Should find parameter <helpParameter> in the function" -Tag Help, Parameter -ForEach $helpParameterNames {
            
            BeforeAll {
                $helpParameter = $_
            }

            $helpParameter -in $parameterNames | Should -BeTrue
        }
    }
```

How do I get the last `-ForEach` to have access to both `$parameterNames` from the `BeforeDiscovery` block and also `$helpParameterNames` from the parent loop?

Answer (score 0):

This is a unique situation and the solution is that some code has to be repeated both in `BeforeDiscovery` and `BeforeAll`. Adding the code to `BeforeDiscovery` means that it can be used in the `Context -ForEach` and adding the code to `BeforeAll` means that it is accessible as a single object inside the child `Describe` blocks.

```ps
Describe "Help Rules" -Tags Build, Help -ForEach $commands {

    BeforeDiscovery {
        $common = 'Debug', 'ErrorAction', 'ErrorVariable', 'InformationAction', 'InformationVariable', 'OutBuffer', 'OutVariable', 'PipelineVariable', 'Verbose', 'WarningAction', 'WarningVariable'
        $parameters = (Get-Command $_.Name).ParameterSets.Parameters | Where-Object -Property Name -NotIn $common | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique
        $help = Get-Help $_.Name -Full -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $helpParameterNames = $help.Parameters.Parameter.Name | Sort-Object -Unique
    }
    
    BeforeAll {
        $commandName = $_.Name

        $help = Get-Help $commandName -Full -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $helpParameterNames = $help.Parameters.Parameter.Name | Sort-Object -Unique
        
        #Define this both in BeforeDiscovery and BeforeAll as it is needed both in the ForEach and also as an array
        $common = 'Debug', 'ErrorAction', 'ErrorVariable', 'InformationAction', 'InformationVariable', 'OutBuffer', 'OutVariable', 'PipelineVariable', 'Verbose', 'WarningAction', 'WarningVariable'
        $parameters = (Get-Command $_.Name).ParameterSets.Parameters | Where-Object -Property Name -NotIn $common | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique
        $parameterNames = $parameters.Name
    }

    Context "General Rules for <commandName>" -ForEach $parameters {
```